# Superposition of Page times - is the Hawking radiation maximally mixed?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, quantum-entanglement, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation

Suppose we have a black hole of mass $M$ at time $t_0$. The black hole has already been radiating Hawking radiation for some time. If no further mass is added to the black hole, suppose over half of the total lifetime Hawking radiation has already been emitted.  However, if an additional mass of $M'$ is later added to the black hole, less than half of the total lifetime Hawking radiation would have been emitted because the total lifetime of the black hole would have been extended.

Suppose we have a control qubit $[|0\rangle+|1\rangle]/\sqrt{2}$ outside the black hole at time $t_0$. It's measured in the computational basis and if its value is 0, no further mass is added to the black hole. Otherwise, a mass of $M'$ is dumped into the black hole. Prior to the control qubit being measured, the black hole is in a superposition of being past and not being passed its Page time. If its past, the Hawking radiation emitted so far would be less than maximally thermally mixed.  Otherwise, it would be maximally thermally mixed. So, at time $t_0$, is the Hawking radiation emitted so far maximally mixed or not?

The issue is Page time is teleologically defined.